# How to serve an MPEG-DASH manifest to Shaka player properly?

Tags: javascript, go, mpeg-dash, shaka

I tried to implement [Shaka Player](https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-basic-usage.html) in my Go project. This is the project structure:

```
.
├── client
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── shaka.js
│   └── shaka-player.compiled.js
└── server
    ├── assets
    │   ├── test_dashinit.mp4
    │   └── test_dash.mpd
    ├── Gopkg.lock
    ├── Gopkg.toml
    ├── main.go
    └── vendor
```

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Video</title>

    <script src="shaka-player.compiled.js" defer></script>
    <script src="shaka.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <video id="video-clip" controls></video>
</body>

</html>
```

My `main.go` file in which I specify routes for `index.html` and `test_dash.mpd`:

```golang
func sendManifest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Open the file.
    manifest, err := os.Open("server/assets/test_dash.mpd")

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)

        return
    }

    defer manifest.Close()

    // Get file size.
    stat, err := manifest.Stat()

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)

        return
    }

    size := strconv.FormatInt(stat.Size(), 10)

    // Set the headers.
    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=manifest.mpd")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/dash+xml")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Length", size)
    // Send the file.
    io.Copy(w, manifest)
}

func main() {
    cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
    fmt.Println(cwd)

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("client"))

    http.Handle("/", fs)
    http.HandleFunc("/manifest", sendManifest)

    http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil)
}
```

When I try to access the manifest with `player.load()`, it just returns `404 Not found`. But when I try to access it in the browser by the same link (`127.0.0.1:5000/manifest`), it's ok and I can download the file. The link from the guide works well. How should I serve the video manifest from my Go server so Shaka player could consume it without any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was enough to specify the scheme:
`http://127.0.0.1:5000/manifest`
instead of just
`127.0.0.1:5000/manifest`.

Comment: In my case, I was having a CORS issue.